# Forcing HTTPS for Main Domain, Not Sub-Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have my site and several sub-domains on a c-Panel server and would like to achieve the following functionality:

**Force HTTPS and WWW for all traffic to example.com for all traffic to my main site -> https://www.example.com/what-ever-page-or-directory**

I also have a *sub.example.com* as sub-domain setup through c-Panel (not re-directed), whose document root is /public_html/sub and this sub-domain doesn't have an SSL. I tried putting in the following HTACCESS code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

which works for redirecting all traffic on the main site, BUT when I try to access my sub-domain, http://sub.example.com, I get a redirect error saying *This webpage has a redirect loop*.

Thanks in advance for any help! I found similar posts but nothing dealing with my specific question. I'm not great with HTACCESS directives and the redirect error is throwing me for a loop. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On

#Exclude subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

To exclude multiple subdomains you can use multiple RewriteConds :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bar.domain.com$
```

or just 1 liner pattern :

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(foo|bar).domain.com$
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @starkeen. This worked! Do you know how I would exclude multiple sub-domains then if I needed to in the future? Thanks again